# Using Oracle ODBC drivers with Windows 7

Tags: oracle, vb6, odbc, driver

I've looked to see if this has been asked before, but only see questions relating to VB6 installations, not .exe files MADE FROM VB6. Apologies if this has been asked and answered.

I have some tools I built with VB6 and our team has been using them successfully for some time now. However, we are migrating to Windows 7 and it seems there are now issues with using the "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver.

I can write in VB.Net, but I don't yet have it and don't know when I'll get it.

Any advice? Time is of the essence here, and a big thanks to all who answer.

Comment: ODBC with Windows 7 should work well. You only have to notice that "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" exists only for x86 (32 bit), thus you must have "Oracle Client 32 bit" installed on your Windows 7. What do you mean by "it seems there are now issues"?

Comment: The Oracle client is 32-bit, so we can rule that out. The error message we get seems to imply that he does not have the driver, but he does. 

Error Details:

Error Code: 80004005 
Description: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: Also, based on other answers I have reviewed, I have tried different suggested connection strings for Windows 7 which circumvent the driver entirely. The error message when using any flavor of such a connection string is that the credentials are denied. This makes me wonder if something I saw on another site is true: that when using VB the creds are dropped, but not when using C#. (http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?736171-RESOLVED-VB6-ADO-Oracle-and-Win7-64-Automation-Error-cannot-connect-to-Oracle)

Comment: Did you specify the ODBC connection? Maybe show your source code.

Comment: Do you use the correct ODBC Adminstrator? When you just open `odbcad32.exe` you run the 64 bit version. You must run `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` for 32 bit version

Comment: Hello, Wernfried--I don't want you to think I'm ignoring your responses. It is a holiday here in the U.S., and I'm stepping away from my work until Monday :-) To answer your first question, yes, I am specifying the ODBC connection, will post code later when I am on my work laptop. To the second question regarding ODBC administrator, that I do not know. I will check into that on Monday. Thank you :-)

Comment: Apologies to take so long to respond, and thank you again for your prompt and helpful responses, Wernfried. This issue has been resolved, though I don't know details. Before I could check on the ODBC administrator, the 1 person who had been migrated to Windows 7 found out on his own that his drivers were not correctly installed; the problem may have been exactly what you mentioned. In any event, once he had them installed properly, my code ran just fine. THANK YOU for your help, Wernfried!

Comment: For anyone reading this with similar troubles, I will find out the details of "incorrect ODBC driver install" and publish them as the answer next week.